# In what sense does Paul use παρακαλέω in 2 Corinthians 10:1?

Tags: 2-corinthians

(KJV)2 Corinthians 10:1

> Now I Paul myself **beseech** you by the meekness and gentleness of Christ, who in presence am base among you, but being absent am bold toward you:

Is this word used of men entreating other men or God pleading with men

Comment: It says: "I, **Paul**, beseech **you**...". How hard is that? See that it continues [in the next verse](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2+Corinthians+10%3A1-2&version=NIV) (v. 2) "I beg **you**...". If there is something you don't understand about this, then explain the problem. Otherwise this looks like a non-question.

Comment: Is your question a) based on the idea of inspiration (thus God not Paul beseeching)? or are you asking b) is this a type and archetype (with Paul's epistle and soon arrival paralleled with God's displeasure and a second coming scenario)? If either - would tag "authorial-intent" be a better fit; and if b) would tag "eschatology" be better? Or are you asking something else? Otherwise, I agree it that it seems a non-question @Dɑvïd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the question is asked because Paul uses the clause, "by the meekness and gentleness of Christ".

Paul brings up the "meekness and gentleness of Christ" to make a point to the Corinthians that he is upbraiding them gently and not sternly, following what he had written in the previous epistle:

> *Shall I come unto you with a rod, or in love and a spirit of meekness?* (1 Corinthians 4:21)

and states later in the current:

> *That I may not seem as if I would terrify you by letters* (2 Corinthians 10:7).

He is being somewhat ironic, however, as it is clear that he has full confidence in God's backing (v.4):

> *For though we walk in the flesh, we do not war after the flesh: (For the weapons of our warfare are not carnal, but mighty through God to
>   the pulling down of strong holds)*

John Chrysostom explains this interpretation of what Paul has written in his Homily ([XXI](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf112.v.xxi.html)) on this passage:

> For in this place he shows both things, both his power, and his
>   philosophy and forbearance; since he so beseeches them, and with such
>   earnestness, that he may not be compelled to come to a display of the
>   avenging power pertaining to him, and to smite and chastise them and
>   exact the extreme penalty. For he implied this in saying, “But I
>   beseech you, that I may not when present show courage with the
>   confidence, wherewith I count to be bold against some which count of
>   us as if we walked according to the flesh.”

Comment: You shouldn't have to "assume". You're very generous, but I don't want to encourage questions of this kind.

Comment: Hi, David.  I think I can appreciate your personal preference for what sorts of questions can and cannot be asked, but I think we are community-based.  ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) states that "If your question is about ... interpretation of a specific Bible passage ... then this is the right place to ask."  The OP had a straightforward question, quoting Bible text, "In what sense does Paul use παρακαλέω in 2 Corinthians 10:1?"  In my opinion, such questions can and should be encouraged.

Comment: Hi - I've posted [some follow-up in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34327090#34327090). Would be happy to explore this more with you there!